# Compare a range to a single cell with multiple values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to hide rows in one workbook/worksheet based on a range of cells. I need to look at each cell in the range and determine if there is a match within a string of a single cell in the initial workbook/worksheet. 
The range of rows contains country names like:

- United States of America
- France
- Antigua and Barbuda
- Argentina

But the cell to compare looks like this:

- United States of America, France, Antigua and Barbuda

I tried to research and put together the code, but I don’t really know what I’m doing. Here is what I have. I am sure the problem is the If statement.

```
vwb.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tabName).Select
For Each c In vwb.Worksheets(tabName).Range("A121:A345").Text

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(InStr(1, twb.Worksheets("Basic_Info”).Range("COS"), c.Value)) Then
Else
vwb.Worksheets(tabName).Rows(c.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If
Next
```

Comment: So loop the Range("A121:A345") and if any country from the range("COS") is found then hide that row? Sounds like you might need 2 loops. Also, you are comparing between 2 workbooks, is that what you intended?

Comment: You also have a ” where you want a "

Comment: Yes, I am trying to compare two workbooks. That's what is confusing me more.

Comment: Yes, look the Range("A121:A345") and if any country from the range("COS") is found, then hide the row in the original range. The "COS" range is just a single cell with concatenated values separated by a comma.

Comment: You can use the Split function then on the value to create the array (see my edit)  or use Scott's simpler method.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am slowly starting to understand everything. Both answers made sense but I used the shorter one to keep it simple. :)

Comment: you can't really go wrong with Scott's answers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler than you the path you have taken (probably in confusion :)).

See below and ask any question if you don't understand how this code differs from what you did:

```
Dim searchRange as Range, findRange as Range, c as Range
Set searchRange = vwb.Worksheets(tabName).Range("A121:A345")
Set findRange = twb.Worksheets("Basic_Info”).Range("COS")

For Each c In searchRange

    If findRange.Find(c.Value, lookin:=xlPart) is Nothing Then

        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True        

    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example framework if you are trying to hide rows where there is a match found in the `COS` range. For ease of testing I change twb to vwb. If you want to hide where there isn't a match then use  `InStr(1, c.Value, countriesArr(i, 1)) = 0`

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim vwb As Workbook
Set vwb = ThisWorkbook

Dim c As Range
Dim tabName As String
tabName = "Sheet1"

Dim i As Long

Dim countriesArr() As String
'countriesArr = vwb.Worksheets("Basic_Info").Range("COS").Value  'twb.
countriesArr = Split(vwb.Worksheets("Basic_Info").Range("COS").Value, ",")
Dim unionRng As Range

For Each c In vwb.Worksheets(tabName).Range("A121:A345")

    For i = LBound(countriesArr) To UBound(countriesArr)

        If InStr(1, c.Value, countriesArr(i)) > 0 Then

            If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then

                 Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, c)

            Else

                Set unionRng = c

            End If

            Exit For

        End If

    Next i

Next c

If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
    unionRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```